# Tibco EMS Capture JMSMessageID Header before calling Send

Tags: tibco-ems

We're using TIBCO EMS to send/receive messages in C#.  Is it possible to capture the JMSHeader's MessageID field, BEFORE a message is sent?
As per this link,
https://kaazing.com/doc/jms/4.0/apidoc/client/dotnet/jms/html/P_Kaazing_JMS_IMessage_JMSMessageID.htm,
the MessageID is set by the provider hence when I check the messageToSend before the MessageProducer.Send() method is called, it is empty.  Once I receive the response though, messageToSend.MessageID is populated.

My question is can i capture MessageID before calling MessageProducer.Send()?